# regex for phone number searching in string which works for every country

Tags: c#, regex

i want to search phone numbers in Google by my script...so i need some regex to search for phone number of every country in a string or html... i have tried the following regex but its not working....`

```
private string findphone(string source)
        {
            string my = "";
            string phone = "";

        string MatchPhoneNumberPattern3 = @"\D(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4})\D";
        MatchCollection mathph3 = Regex.Matches(source, MatchPhoneNumberPattern3);
        foreach (Match match4 in mathph3)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match4.Captures)
            {
                if (my.ContainsKey(capture.Value) == false)
                {
                    phone = capture.Value.ToString();

                }
            }
        }
```

kindly help me regarding this, i want  such a regex that works for every country phone numbers...plz

Comment: You can't do that.  New phone number formats show up all the time.

Comment: What if the phone number format of a country changes? My country's phone number format is changing this September.

Comment: `its not working` is a completely useless problem description.

Comment: Google has an open-source library for handling phone numbers (https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) that is several hundred K and includes a separate format file for every country.  You won't be able to replicate that with a regex.

Comment: Check with the NSA, there must be a way.

Comment: @sln NSA apparently has had issues with regexes, not sure you'd want country code '20' mixed-up with '200'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you first need to visit the ITU (International Telecommunications Union) website regarding National Numbering Plans:

http://www.itu.int/oth/T0202.aspx?parent=T0202

This is a good resource, too: [The World Telephone Numbering Guide](http://www.wtng.info/)

Then you'll need to work through the many different numbering plans and integrate them into a single regular expression. And deal with the fact that people represent phone numbers differently depening on context (depending on where you're dialing from and to, different components of the phone number may or may not be required and the format of the number may change. For instance, all these represent the same subscriber line in North America, depending on context:

- 555-1234
- 1-555-1234
- 206-555-1234
- 1-206-555-1234
- 00-1-206-555-1234 (direct-dialed from France, among other countries)
- 0011-1-206-555-1234 (direct-dialed from Australia)
- 119-1-206-555-1234 (direct-dialed from Cuba)
- Etc. There are more.

Don't forget that there are lots of conventions for notating a phone number, too.

- 206.555.1234
- 206/555.1234
- (206) 555-1234
- 206-555-1234
- etc., not to mention the international standard, where the number is prefixed by the country code:

  - +1:206-555-1234 (NANP)
  - +33:xx.xx.xx.xx.xx (France)

    And in France, the first digit of the 10-digit phone number might change depending on what *carrier* the subscriber is currently tied to: 01.xx.xx.xx.xx if a Paris subscriber is currently getting phone service from the PTT, and 71.xx.xx.xx.xx if the same Paris subscriber has switched to Cegetel.

are all in pretty common use.

Other countries are at least as complex.

Once you've got all that in place, then you'll need to monitor the ITU web site for changes: since you're not a "telecom operators/service provider or a telecom Administration", you're not eligible to subscribe to the ITU's notification service.

Further, you'll need to provide backwards compatability as people aren't necessarily going to quickly change how they've recorded phone numbers when the numbering plan changes.

Comment: Good answer to a poor question.